# Generate PDF using domPDF and it into JSON response

Tags: laravel

I want to generate a pdf using domPDF and turn it into JSON response for my angular front end to consume it. Until now, I manage to generate the pdf and haven't turn it into JSON response.
Here is my code for now

```
 public function generateClaimFormPDF(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'user_id'  => 'required',
        ]);
        $user = User::find($request['user_id']);
        $customers = CustomerDetail::join('sprayer_earns', 'customer_details.job_id', '=', 'sprayer_earns.job_id')
            ->where("sprayer_earns.user_id", "=", $request['user_id'])
            ->where('is_receive', '=', '2')
            ->get();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('claim-form', compact('customers','user'));
        return $pdf->download('commission-claim-form.pdf');

    }
```

Comment: That's not a question.

Comment: Save to disk and serve it as base 64?

Comment: so you means I need to save it in public folder and retrieve it and change it to base 64 ?